# Returning columns as rows

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have a table with some name references.

With the query:

```
SELECT id, n1, n2, n3
FROM nametable
```

the table returns:

```
+----+--------+-------+--------+
| id |   n1   |  n2   |   n3   |
+----+--------+-------+--------+
|  1 | Larry  | Bob   | Mo     |
|  2 | Sara   | May   | (NULL) |
|  3 | Keiran | Lenny | (NULL) |
+----+--------+-------+--------+
```

I'd like to return it as:

```
+----+--------+
| id |   n    |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Larry  |
|  1 | Bob    |
|  1 | Mo     |
|  2 | Sara   |
|  2 | May    |
|  3 | Keiran |
|  3 | Lenny  |
+----+--------+
```

Note that (NULL) values are not returned in the final result

I did some research and found something called "pivot tables". However, none of the examples matches my condition. In which i'd like to keep the id in every row.

How would i do this using queries?

Comment: I don't believe MySQL has a `PIVOT` like for example SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the nearest in mysql:

```
select * from (
(select id, n1 as n from nametable) union all
(select id, n2 as n from nametable) union all
(select id, n3 as n from nametable)
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also unpivot your table this way

```
SELECT id, 
       CASE n 
          WHEN 1 THEN n1
          WHEN 2 THEN n2
          WHEN 3 THEN n3
       END n
  FROM nametable t CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT 1 n UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 
) i
HAVING n IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY id, n;
```

Output:

```
| ID |      N |
|----|--------|
|  1 |    Bob |
|  1 |  Larry |
|  1 |     Mo |
|  2 |    May |
|  2 |   Sara |
|  3 | Keiran |
|  3 |  Lenny |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5058/2)** demo